# How to evaluate which factor explains more of DV variance by eyeballing a violin plot

Tags: r, categorical-data, ggplot2

When glancing over data, I want to be able to quickly grasp which independent variable (factor) explains most of variance of a dependent variable (continuous). One way of reaching quick conclusions is by visualizing data. Say that I choose a violin plot (in R/ggplot) -- how could I compare three plots, both have same y-axis variable but different x-axis factor variables, to superficially conclude which plot explains more of DV variance?

### Demonstration with data

Going over `mtcars` data, I'm interested in the `mpg` metric. I'd like to see which categorical factor, either `cyl`, `gear`, or `carb` explains more variance of `mpg`.

#### mpg by cyl

```r
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
   geom_violin() + 
   geom_jitter(height = 0, width = 0.1)
```

[image: mpg_by_cyl]

#### mpg by gear

```r
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(factor(gear), mpg)) + 
   geom_violin() + 
   geom_jitter(height = 0, width = 0.1)
```

[image: mpg_by_gear]

#### mpg by carb

```r
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(factor(carb), mpg)) + 
   geom_violin() + 
   geom_jitter(height = 0, width = 0.1)
```

[image: mpg_by_carb]

- Would there be any "rules of thumb" for quick evaluation?
- Also, are you familiar with some resources that could educate me on this specific question? Googling didn't yield relevant results, but maybe because I didn't use accurate search terms.

Comment: Roughly speaking, you're looking for strong correlation (positive or negative). Cyl has unambiguous negative correlation with MPG, not much vertical variation, almost complete vertical separation. Gear may have slight positive correlation. Carb has negative correlation, but not as strong as Cyl; more vertical variation. // So I'd guess Cyl is likely to explain more variance in MPG than Carb, and much more than Gear.

Comment: So would you say that evaluating which factor explains more of the DV variance could be boiled down to three checks: (1) vertical variation within each factor (the denser the better); (2) vertical separation between factors (the more separate the better); and (3) the overall scatter as an indicator to strength of correlation (the steeper the better, as it is with correlation).
?

Comment: also, @BruceET, please consider posting your comment as an answer so I could choose it.